# Huge filesize when making gif with python Wand

Tags: python, image-processing, animated-gif, wand, magickwand

I'm trying to do a gif of liquid rescales with Wand, but when the gif is saved into a file the filesize is obscene **huge**, I mean, from a JPG image of 1539x2048 and 242 KB it yields a gif of **55 MB**. Besides, when calling `image.make_blob()` it takes a lot of time to generate the blob.

```py
from wand.image import Image

def gifynize(image: str, level: int = 50) -> bytes:

    with Image() as gif:
        with Image(filename=image) as source:
            width, height = source.width, source.height

            target_witdh = width * (100 - level) // 100
            target_height = height * (100 - level) // 100

            width_steps = (width - target_x) // (10 * 3)
            height_steps = (height - target_y) // (10 * 3)
           
            with source.clone() as clone:
                gif.sequence.append(clone)

            for _width, _height in zip(
                range(width, target_width, -width_steps), range(heigth, target_heigth, -heigth_steps)
            ):
                source.liquid_rescale(_width, height)
                with source.clone() as clone:
                    clone.resize(width, height) # Bring back to the original size
                    gif.sequence.append(clone)

        gif.format = "gif"
        return gif.make_blob()
```

I have tried `gif.type = "optimize"`, `gif.optimize_layers()` and `gif.optimize_transparency()` but the final gif filesize doesn't change. Also, when using heavy images (2 MB), it throws a segmentation fault when calling `img.make_blob()`.

Any help is welcome.